# With PHP-curl: Security header is not valid

Tags: php, curl, paypal

I am using this for the PayPal Express Checkout API, but I get an error:

```
ACK=Failure&VERSION=78&BUILD=000000&L_ERRORCODE0=10002&L_SHORTMESSAGE0=Security%20error&L_LONGMESSAGE0=Security%20header%20is%20not%20valid&L_SEVERITYCODE0=Error
```

Code:

```
$request = 'USER=myuser.de&PWD=mypass&SIGNATURE=mysig&METHOD=SetExpressCheckout&VERSION=78&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=SALE&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=19&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=EUR&cancelUrl=http://xyz.biz/index.php?id=16&returnUrl=http://xyz.biz/abc/';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$result = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

What can I do?

Comment: Are the API credentials you using from Live PayPal account from your PayPal Sandbox account?

Comment: if(curl_exec($ch) === false)
{
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
else
{
    echo 'Operation completed without any errors';
} Try this to find what error are you getting.

Answer (score 0):

Security header is not valid is typically due to having your API credentials entered incorrectly.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp");
```

It looks like you are sending to your live environment. Be sure you are using the correct credentials.

When I use your string and curl call with my credentials I get a positive resposne:

```
Array
(
    [TOKEN] => EC-8JH22470WY0704826
    [TIMESTAMP] => 2015-08-11T17:24:08Z
    [CORRELATIONID] => 18a347794c5a1
    [ACK] => Success
    [VERSION] => 78
    [BUILD] => 000000
)
```

Comment: Yes you are right. I used the loggin-data for the live-server. It works when I remove .sandbox from the URL.
Question: where can I find / generate USER, PWD and SIGNATURE for the sandbox-server?

Comment: You log into http://developer.paypal.com . There is a "Dashboard" link at the top. Once you click that link you'll have an "Accounts" link on the left. This is where you manage your sandbox accounts. Your API credentials will be available on business accounts. They can be viewed by clicking the arrow to the left of the name ans selecting "Profile" There is an "API Credentials" tab in the profile.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the website where I can create the necessary Sandbox-account:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/sb_create-accounts/